# Pathfinder result sightly different from expected!

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I'm making this icon with a base vector and white strokes with variable profiles (right image) and I wanted to unify them as a single object, so I expanded the strokes and used Pathfinder's difference (left image)

[image]
They appear identical, and they should, I guess... But when I zoom out, the one I used pathfinding look like it bled or something like that.

How can I make it look like the original?

Comment: You zoom out or scale down? There is a difference between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zooming is only a preview inside Illustrator. What counts is **how it prints** or **how it displays** in the final use (web, app, ...). My best guess for the effect that you are seeing is that Illustrator calculates the preview for strokes and for surfaces differently.

Comment: I exported both versions in a pdf and the results are exactly the same. I believe you are right, but do you think that is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I suspect that this behavior will be different on every screen you use. Have you tested that?

Comment: tested on two screens different, all the same

Comment: My point was that you will see this behavior on every screen, just a little different depending on the screen. Ergo, you can't "fix it" in Illustrator.

Comment: I had a similar problem working with svg files. they are rendered different in every browser. the only way you have full control over it is by making it a bitmap image

Comment: sorry for the 2 year late accept... totally forgot about this question!